# Best way to Graph/Node trace in Oracle/Sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have an Oracle database that contains a connectivity model which I access through terminal using sqlplus.

The data is structured similarly to what's shown below:

```
StreetName,Node1,Node2,Zone

Residential1, 10, 11, USA
Local1, 11, 12, USA
Local2, 12, 13, USA
.
.
.
Freeway1, 400, 401, USA
```

I would normally extract the DB and analyze it with a language like python, but because the data is updated and changed frequently and it takes a long time to pull out the data for python, I'd like to find out if I can move this process to run directly by logging into sqlplus.

I am trying to find a way to write a query that traces the nodes in the database, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about this because I've never written a conditional query that loops so I would appreciate if I could receive guidance on best practice.

For example, based on the data shown above, if I wanted to take the record 'Residential1' and trace its nodes to find out the first 'Freeway' it is connected to, I'd want to write a query that finds other records connected to Node1 and Node2 and then traces out the connectivity for each record until it reaches a record labeled as 'Freeway' and returns the result.

Now I'd like to scale this solution out to do this with say, all records labeled 'Residential' and such.

Is PL/SQL the best way to go about this or do normal queries have the capability of accomplishing this task effectively?

Comment: Have you tried writing [a hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html); or looked into [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BCEJGIBG)? It might be easier to understand your issue with a complete sample data set and expected results for that data (plus your best attempt so far and what it produced, if you have one).

Comment: I have not taken a look at these topics yet, but I will read what you linked and give it a shot. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AlexPoole I took your advice yesterday and read through your links. I tried to apply the recursive subquery since it seemed to perform better, however I am having some issues in merging the data together from several tables. 

I opened another question, if you have a chance to provide your input when you have some time I'd really appreciate it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732344/how-to-write-involved-recursive-subquery-in-sqlplus-w-multiple-tables-to-trace