# How to write involved recursive subquery in sqlplus w/ multiple tables to trace nodes?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to create a report that maps loads on a circuit to their respective power source (Transformer).

All of the devices are in separate tables and interconnected in the database: Loads, Switches, Lines, Wires, Transformers.

For simplicity's sake, I will show an example where a load is connected to a transformer directly through switches only:

Load table:

```
LoadNumber, SectionNumber, BusNumber
100         54             3000
```

Switch table:

```
SwitchNumber, FromSectionNumber, ToSectionNumber, State, BusNumber
1             54                 105              Closed 3000
2             105                106              Closed 3000
3             106                500              Open   3000
4             105                999              Closed 3000
5             999                700              Closed 3000
```

Transformer table:

```
TransformerNumber, FromSectionNumber, ToSectionNumber, FromBus, ToBus
5000               800                700              2000     3000
5001               801                701              2000     3000
```

In the above example, Transformer #5000 is connected to Load #100 via connectivity through the switches in the table, and energized because there is a closed circuit (Closed switches linking the transformer and load together).

I am trying to write a query that can generate an output similar to something like this:

```
LoadNumber, TransformerNumber
100         5000
```

Which represents that Load #100 is being powered by Transformer #5000

I was able to successfully get a query using 1 table (Switches) to find the Transformer they're linked to, but I'm a little lost on how to involve all of the tables to get a complete view of the network.

What I got so far was:

```
WITH T3 AS
(SELECT SWITCHNAME, SWITCHNUMBER, PSEUDOSWITCH, FROMSECTIONNUMBER, TOSECTIONNUMBER, NORMALSWITCHINGDEVICESTATE, BUSNUMBER
FROM SWITCHINGDEVICE
WHERE UPPER(NORMALSWITCHINGDEVICESTATE) = 'CLOSED'
AND BUSNUMBER = 3484),
T2 AS
(SELECT TRANSFORMERNUMBER, TRANSFORMERNAME, FROMSECTIONNUMBER, TOSECTIONNUMBER, FROMBUSNUMBER, TOBUSNUMBER
FROM TRANSFORMER
WHERE TOBUSNUMBER = 3484),
T4 AS
(SELECT DEVICENUMBER, DEVICENAME, FROMSECTIONNUMBER, TOSECTIONNUMBER, FROMBUSREF, TOBUSREF
FROM PSA_SERIESREACTIVEDEVICE
WHERE TOBUSREF = 3484),
T5 AS
(SELECT LINENUMBER, LINENAME, FROMSECTIONNUMBER, TOSECTIONNUMBER, FROMBUSNUMBER, TOBUSNUMBER
FROM LINE
WHERE TOBUSNUMBER = 3484 AND FROMBUSNUMBER = 3484),
T1 AS
(SELECT A.BUSNUMBER, A.LOADNUMBER, A.LOADNAME, B.TRANSFORMERNUMBER, B.TRANSFORMERNAME
FROM LOADDEFINITION A, TRANSFORMER B
WHERE A.LOADNUMBER = 5572
AND A.BUSNUMBER = B.TOBUSNUMBER
---TEST LOAD
UNION ALL
SELECT T1.BUSNUMBER, T1.LOADNUMBER, T1.LOADNAME, T2.TRANSFORMERNUMBER, T2.TRANSFORMERNAME
FROM LOADDEFINITION T1, TRANSFORMER T2, SWITCHINGDEVICE T3, PSA_SERIESREACTIVEDEVICE T4, LINE T5, SWITCHINGDEVICE T6
WHERE
T1.LOADNUMBER = 5572 AND T1.BUSNUMBER = 3484
AND T2.TOBUSNUMBER = T1.BUSNUMBER
AND T3.BUSNUMBER = T1.BUSNUMBER
AND T4.TOBUSREF = T1.BUSNUMBER
AND T5.TOBUSNUMBER = T1.BUSNUMBER
AND T5.FROMBUSNUMBER = T5.TOBUSNUMBER
AND T3.BUSNUMBER = T2.TOBUSNUMBER
AND T4.TOBUSREF = T2.TOBUSNUMBER
AND T5.TOBUSNUMBER = T2.TOBUSNUMBER
AND T3.BUSNUMBER = T4.TOBUSREF
AND T5.TOBUSNUMBER = T3.BUSNUMBER
AND T5.TOBUSNUMBER = T4.TOBUSREF
AND T6.BUSNUMBER = T1.BUSNUMBER
---take into consideration downstream loops
AND ((T1.SECTIONNUMBER = T3.TOSECTIONNUMBER AND T1.SECTIONNUMBER = T6.TOSECTIONNUMBER)
    OR
     (T1.SECTIONNUMBER = T3.FROMSECTIONNUMBER AND T1.SECTIONNUMBER = T6.FROMSECTIONNUMBER))
AND (T3.FROMSECTIONNUMBER = T2.TOSECTIONNUMBER)
AND (T3.FROMSECTIONNUMBER = T6.TOSECTIONNUMBER)
AND T6.NORMALSWITCHINGDEVICESTATE = T3.NORMALSWITCHINGDEVICESTATE
)
SELECT T1.BUSNUMBER, T1.LOADNUMBER, T1.LOADNAME, T2.TRANSFORMERNUMBER, T2.TRANSFORMERNAME FROM T1, T2
```

But rather than returning back 1 result as I would expect (Since I hardcoded a single load), I'm getting back a list showing all of the transformers.

Representing that with the example data, the result looks something like:

```
LoadNumber, TransformerNumber
100         5000
100         5001
```

I've been playing around with this for some time and not sure which part of this query is messed up.

Edit:

If I wanted to write a query to obtain the desired result using the example dataset, how would that be accomplished?

Something with the logic of: select loadnumber, transformernumber where load has a live connection to the transformer through closed switch devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simplified example (sort of, I started to use your real table names, but it's the original data) you can get all of the routes through multiple switches with:

```
with rcte (rootsectionnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber) as (
  select fromsectionnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber
  from switchingdevice
  where normalswitchingdevicestate = 'CLOSED'
  union all
  select r.rootsectionnumber, sd.fromsectionnumber, sd.tosectionnumber
  from rcte r
  join switchingdevice sd on sd.fromsectionnumber = r.tosectionnumber
)
select rootsectionnumber, tosectionnumber from rcte;

ROOTSECTIONNUMBER TOSECTIONNUMBER
----------------- ---------------
               54             105
              105             106
              105             999
              999             700
               54             106
              105             500
               54             999
              105             700
               54             500
               54             700
```

one of which has an end-to-end route from section 54 to 700; and you can then join that to the load definition:

```
with rcte (rootsectionnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber) as (
  select fromsectionnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber
  from switchingdevice
  where normalswitchingdevicestate = 'CLOSED'
  union all
  select r.rootsectionnumber, sd.fromsectionnumber, sd.tosectionnumber
  from rcte r
  join switchingdevice sd on sd.fromsectionnumber = r.tosectionnumber
)
select ld.loadnumber, t.transformernumber
from loaddefinition ld
join rcte r on r.rootsectionnumber = ld.sectionnumber
join transformer t on t.tosectionnumber = r.tosectionnumber
where ld.loadnumber = 100;

LOADNUMBER TRANSFORMERNUMBER
---------- -----------------
       100              5000
```

Or if you need to include the `busnumber` in the logic (based on a brief look at your larger query...):

```
with rcte (rootsectionnumber, busnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber) as (
  select fromsectionnumber, busnumber, fromsectionnumber, tosectionnumber
  from switchingdevice
  where normalswitchingdevicestate = 'CLOSED'
  union all
  select r.rootsectionnumber, r.busnumber, sd.fromsectionnumber, sd.tosectionnumber
  from rcte r
  join switchingdevice sd on sd.fromsectionnumber = r.tosectionnumber
  and sd.busnumber = r.busnumber
)
select ld.loadnumber, t.transformernumber
from loaddefinition ld
join rcte r on r.rootsectionnumber = ld.sectionnumber
and r.busnumber = ld.busnumber
join transformer t on t.tosectionnumber = r.tosectionnumber
and t.tobusnumber = r.busnumber
where ld.loadnumber = 100;

LOADNUMBER TRANSFORMERNUMBER
---------- -----------------
       100              5000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67b669a45e9209c4ee07d57251c7de6d)

Adding in your other tables will obviously complicate things a bit, but it isn't clear quite how they're all related.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to look over my work, I think what you have shown me is a good starting point on how I should structure my query, I will take what you provided and try to play around with it, hopefully netting the desired result and update the question w/ the solution once I figure it out. I've marked your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: One question, in order to map the nodes from other tables to be considered in this query, should all of the other tables be joined in the RTCE definition along w/ the switching device? I thought each table would need to be defined separately, but based on how you wrote it, I think it would be possible to combine it all in 1 definition. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Your final solution probably won't be useful to future visitors. But if you try to adapt it to include the other tables and can't get that to work then you can ask a new question with sample data for all of the tables and scenarios you need. It's a bit hard to decipher from the attempt in this question *8-)

Comment: @BenCWang - it depends how they're related really. It could get complicated if you go repeatedly from say line to transformer to line to transformer, rather than line to series-of-transformers.

Comment: They contain different data, but all of the tables at least possess DeviceName, SectionNumber, BusNumber (From and To Section/Bus if it's 2 nodes, otherwise just 1 such as the Load).

Comment: Yea, the connectivity is actually pretty complicated. And the from/tosection is also interchangeable i.e. you might be getting the power source from backfeeding so assuming it leads in a From-To relationship is not a correct assumption. I wrote an A-star algorithm in python to run this trace/report but I was requested by users to have the process run directly in Oracle. I get the feeling that maybe I should start learning some PL/SQL to accomplish the same task that I did in python? Perhaps I'm overreaching by trying to use recursive subqueries for this?

Comment: Again, it really depends on the details, I'm afraid. You can do an awful lot with SQL and generally should only fall back to PL/SQL for things that are impossible. This sounds complicated but feasible based on what you've said - maybe a combination of recursion and out joins will do, but can't really tell at this point I'm afraid.